# View background image width and height taken automatically from an image

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

How can I automatically get size of backgroundImage and assign it to view width and height? In .tss file.

**NOTE:** In **.tss** file, not in .js file. (I know the code in .js file)

**EDIT**

view.xml

```
 <View id="innerView">
     <ImageView id="middleImage"/>
 </View>
```

view.tss

```
"#innerView":{
zIndex: 2,
height: 'auto',
width: 'auto',
left: "10dp",
right: "10dp",
top: "10dp",
},"#middleImage":{
    image: '/images/iconbg.png',  //  put your image path here
    left: "10dp",
    right: "10dp",
    top: "10dp",
    height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    width: Ti.UI.SIZE,
},
```

i want to get size of image (middleImage) and assign to the upper view (innerView) so that my view can adjust its size according to the image

Comment: have you worked on titanium? its .tss file

Comment: Ok. Then show us your .js procedure - it would be easier to get what you need.

Comment: i have edited my question. please check

Comment: Set heigth and width of both (middleImage and innerView) to Ti.UI.SIZE and remove left or right

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question but setting the width/height of #innerView to Ti.UI.SIZE would adjust the size to the #middleImage size. Make sure to remove left/right because you can't have both, either its the size of the middleImage or it will have the size of the screen width - 10dp*2

Answer (score 0):

Well,I think there's no need for you to use two UI components solve your problem. Just one is enougth:

**.xml**

```
<View id='innerView'/>
```

**.tss**

```
"#innerView":{
  top: '10dp',
  width: 'Ti.UI.SIZE',
  height: 'Ti.UI.SIZE',

  zIndex: 2,
  backgroundImage:'/images/iconbg.png'  //put your image path here
}
```

Or try like this:
**.xml**

```
<ImageView id='middleImage'/>
```

**.tss**

```
"#middleImage":{
  top: '10dp',
  width: 'Ti.UI.SIZE',
  height: 'Ti.UI.SIZE',

  zIndex: 2,
  image:'/images/iconbg.png'  //put your image path here
}
```

If you really need two UI components, and set property **Ti.UI.SIZE** to both of them, there're maybe something looks strange. Because, you have to know that **Ti.UI.SIZE** is mean that the **child-view** like the **ImageView** you set in the **father-view** **View** should make it's **width** and **height** fill it's father; however, once you also set the property to the father **View** ,it's means the **View** should make it's **width** and **height** fill its father--maybe a **Window**, and then it's maybe will looks strange.

**.xml**

```
 <View id="innerView">
   <ImageView id="middleImage"/>
 </View>
```

**.tss**

```
"#innerView":{
  top: '10dp',
  zIndex: 2,
  width: 'Ti.UI.SIZE',
  height: 'Ti.UI.SIZE'
}

"#middleImage":{
  width: 'Ti.UI.SIZE',
  height: 'Ti.UI.SIZE',
  image: '/images/iconbg.png'  //put your image path here
}
```